# Only the first value in the array is assigned to Range in Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I have to input the data of one column into Excel. So, I wrote the code like this:

```cs
double[] array = new double[cavity];

for (var i = 0; i < cavity; i++)
{
  // The process of calculating data
  // double data = ...

  array[i] = data;
}

worksheet.Range["A1", $"A{cavity}"].Value2 = array;
```

Execution is normal, but the problem is that all values in `Range` are fixed as the first value in the `array`.

What's the problem? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `worksheet.Range` is a two-dimensional array, you have to declare `double[]` as `double[,]`.

**Even a single line requires the use of a two-dimensional array.**

```cs
double[,] array = new double[cavity, 1];

for (var i = 0; i < cavity; i++)
{
  // The process of calculating data
  // double data = ...

  array[i, 0] = data;
}

worksheet.Range["A1", $"A{cavity}"].Value2 = array;
```